# Using a Dynamic path for a csv file

Tags: java, filepath

I have a program that saves on a file. The current code is set for the file to save on a specific path, but when I run the program from a different computer the program doesn't work and I need to change the path everytime.

```
 public CreateCustomer() {
    initComponents();

    ArrayList<String> ConsIDList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String csvFileToRead = "E:\\ryan_assignment_sit2\\ConsID\\consID.csv"; // Reads the CSV File. 
    BufferedReader br = null; // Creates a buffer reader.
    String line = "";
    String splitBy = ","; // Reader Delimiter

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead)); // Buffer Reader with file name to read.
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //While there is a line to read.
            reader = new Scanner(line);
            reader.useDelimiter(splitBy);

            while (reader.hasNext()) { // While there is a next value (token).
                ConsIDList.add(reader.next());
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) { // Exception Handler if the File is not Found.
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException exception) { // Input/Output exception
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close(); // Close the Scanner.
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I placed the file in the a subfolder in the program with the name ConsID and I tried changing the path file to

```
String csvFileToRead = "..\\ConsID\\consID.csv";
```

But the file can't be read from the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String csvFileToRead = "E:\ryan_assignment_sit2\ConsID\consID.csv"; 
The above path will only be applicable to windows. If you execute the program in linux environment you will get an Filenotfoundexception. Eventhough you change the file, again you are hardcoding the file path. 
Better you can get it as runtime parameters so that the program will be executed irrespective of OS.

Comment: The program will run only on windows based computer so I don't think this will effect. But I need to open the program on multiple computer and I would like to know if it is possible to set a path that reads from the root folder of the program maybe

Comment: Place it in a shared folder and access it using HTTP so that you can read the file.

Comment: Every computer needs to have a individual file, so ideally the file will be in the same folder of the application. What I am looking for is a way to use a dynamic path like the program will search directly the same folder where it launched from

Answer (score 0):

If you are running you program from command line then you can place the csv file in your classpath (root folder where the class files are generated) and refer to it as below:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("consID.csv"));
```

Comment: that was the first thing I tried but I was given an error, I kept getting that getResourceAsStream(String) cant be referenced from a static context, thats why I had to set a spesific path temporarly to finish the program

Comment: Then what is the issue from calling from non-static context

Comment: I didn't understand the question, can you please explain is simpler way, I am new to coding and this is just an assignment that I am doing

Comment: when you tried getResourceAsStream you must be using some non-static variable from a static method thats why you got "cant be referenced from a static context". So you can try making a calling from non-static method.

Comment: @RyanTheuma .. are you able to get through this?

Comment: sorry for the late reply yes I managed to take both answer and modify them and get a good answer

Comment: @RyanTheuma .. thanks, please accept which ever you like to make question answered so that other users can refer to it